# How to solve this percentage problem?

Tags: arithmetic, percentages

Question:

"A tax is levied on 60% of the cultivated land. The revenue department collected total Rs 384000 through the tax from the village of Sukhiya. Sukhiya a very rich farmer paid only Rs 480 as tax. Percentage of total land of Sukhiya over the total taxable land of the village is what? "

Doubt:

I considered proportionality structure and got a wrong answer(0.125 %). I really do not know where I went wrong. A guided guidance about the same is most welcome.

Comment: Perhaps the key is "total land of Sukhiya" vs. "total taxable land of the village" - so in his case we use all land, and for village only taxable, so you would be off by a factor of $60\%$

Comment: I could not really get you can you show me a few steps?

Comment: You should really accept Alex K's answer

Answer (score 3):

$384000$ is the taxed price of $60$% of the total land. If Sukhiya only paid 480, he paid $0.00125$ of the tax, or $0.125$%, as you put in your answer. However, this price was only for $60$% of the total land, because the tax only covers $60$% of the land. So, from the total, you would have to do
$60$% $*$ $0.125$%, leading to a total percent of $0.075$%.

Comment: I would have asked for clarification in the comments, but I don't have enough reputation to do so; apologies ahead of time if I misunderstood the question.

Comment: I think the answer should be (0.125/60%)% because 0.125%=Taxable_{sukhiya}/Taxable_{total}=Sukhiya's Plot/Total plot and Taxable plot = 60% * Total plot